# Using an argument value in argument declaration

Tags: ruby, thor

I wish to specify the default value of an argument based on the value of a previously declared argument. In this example, the `handlerSendPort` default value should be `handlerRecvPort + 1`

```
require "thor/group"  
module Noov
  class App < Thor::Group
    include Thor::Actions

    argument :name, type: :string, desc: "The name of the project to create"
    argument :handlerRecvPort, type: :numeric, desc: "The 0MQ recv port number on the handler side (random if not specified)", optional: true, default: rand(2**16-1024)+1024+1
    argument :handlerSendPort, type: :numeric, desc: "The 0MQ send port number on the handler side (recv port + 1 if not specified)", optional: true, default: handlerRecvPort+1
    argument :handlerUUID, type: :string, desc: "The mongrel2 server UUID (project name if not specified)", optional: true, default: name
    desc "Creates a project directory for a new website. Fully equipped to support BDD with Cucumber"

  end
end
```

This fails with:

`undefined local variable or method`handlerRecvPort' for Noov::App:Class (NameError)`

I realize that the argument value is not available in the context of the class evaluation (although I had hoped for some metamagic to make it work), so how can I access the argument value at this point?

Comment: As a workaround, I assign the corresponding instances variables in the  relevant tasks definitions:
  
    def create_config_ru
      @ handlerSendPort ||= handlerRecvPort+1
      @ handlerID ||= name
      template('../templates/config.ru.tt', "#{name}/config.ru")
    end

This works with or w/o default values.